# django authentication using @login_required

Tags: django, django-authentication

is @login_required decorator an alternate to login() and authenticate() in django?, Anyone can you please elaborate it?. Thanks in advance for the reply

Comment: as the name indicate, the **`login_required`** decorator will not permit you to access the view content/action unless you are authenticated

Answer (score 1):

The @login_required decorator and LoginRequiredMixin don't actually perform authentication. They check there is a currently logged in user and of not, redirect to the login page.